# Calculate size of Object in Java

Tags: java, memory, memory-management, data-structures

I want to record how much memory (in bytes, hopefully) an object takes up for a project (I'm comparing sizes of data structures) and it seems like there is no method to do this in Java. Supposedly, C/C++ has `sizeOf()` method, but this is nonexistant in Java. I tried recording the free memory in the JVM with `Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` before and after creating the object and then recording the difference, but it would only give 0 or 131304, and nothing in between, regardless of the number of elements in the structure. Help please!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: You may want to try the totalMemory() and then freeMemory() and subtract those instead.

Comment: I recommend you taking a look at Jbellis JAMM. (https://github.com/jbellis/jamm) It relies on the instrumentation agent mentioned above but encapsulates some hepful utilities to deep measure the footprint of an entire object-graph. Looks simple and pretty cool to me.

Comment: it will work only for primitive structures, not for structures with collections or something. Size of int[].class can be few bytes, but size of new int[1e9] will be few gigabytes.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can use the [`java.lang.instrumentation`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html) package.

It has a method that can be used to get the implementation specific approximation of object size, as well as overhead associated with the object.

The answer that Sergey linked has a great example, which I'll repost here, but you should have already looked at from his comment:

```
import java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation;

public class ObjectSizeFetcher {
    private static Instrumentation instrumentation;

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation inst) {
        instrumentation = inst;
    }

    public static long getObjectSize(Object o) {
        return instrumentation.getObjectSize(o);
    }
}
```

Use `getObjectSize`:

```
public class C {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        System.out.println(ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(new C()));
    }
}
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object#52682)

Comment: Says "The only way to access an instance of the Instrumentation interface is for the JVM to be launched in a way that indicates the agent class - see the package specification. The Instrumentation instance is passed to the premain method of the agent class. Once an agent acquires the Instrumentation instance, the agent may call methods on the instance at any time. " <-- how do I do that (in Eclipse)?

Comment: Don't I have to specify how the JVM launches? I tried it and it keeps giving me NullPointerException

Comment: Edit your post above with what you tried.

Comment: Don't know how this answer has gotten so many upvotes. It completely ignores the fact that it is necessary to compile an agent class to pass to the JVM as an argument. Not doing so will render instrumentation null, and trigger a NullPointerException. Here's the proper answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object

Comment: There must be something not quite right with this approach when trying to find my web session size: it reports 40, while ObjectGraphMeasurer (https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer) reports "Footprint{Objects=34, References=52, Primitives=[float, int x 19, char x 257, long x 2, byte x 68557]}". ObjectGraphMeasurer is clearly the winner.

Comment: Is the long value the number of bytes ?

Answer (score 94):

Look into https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer.
Guava uses it internally, and `ObjectGraphMeasurer` is especially straightforward to use out-of-the-box, without any special command-line arguments.

```
import objectexplorer.ObjectGraphMeasurer;

public class Measurer {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> hashset = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      hashset.add(random.nextInt());
    }
    System.out.println(ObjectGraphMeasurer.measure(hashset));
  }
}
```

Comment: This was pretty helpful. Even the other one was very easy to make it work. Have you used this before?

Comment: I've used memory-measurer before, yes.  (I contribute to Guava, and I did mention that we use it internally.  ;) )

Comment: Instant response. that's why i love SO. thanks a ton. I am trying to use it to measure up a memory activity. it has come in very handy.

Comment: I suspect that the most frequent SO users come here to procrastinate -- so of course we're on here _all the time,_ and we respond to comments instantly.

Comment: @LouisWasserman if I am getting an output of Footprint{Objects=40004, References=92773, Primitives=[int x 40004, float]}, what is the total size?

Comment: That varies depending on your JVM.  If you want to measure bytes, then you should be using `MemoryMeasurer` from the same project; follow the instructions there.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If I use 64 bit JVM, can you tell me how to do the calculations?

Comment: You need to know if CompressedOops is on, but in that case you should assume an Object has a 12 byte overhead, and that references, ints, and floats each take 4 bytes.

Comment: Very helpful. But this jar has a dependency of guava. It's not a executable jar :(

Comment: @kamushin not sure why that matters?

Comment: @LouisWasserman emmmm..I added all jars in lib into my build path, but when I run my server, I got `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/base/Predicates`. So I have to add `guava` dependency in my `pom.xml`.  It seems `guava-r09.jar` does't work.

Comment: So you have to add the dependency?  So what?

Comment: @LouisWasserman I can't find any file describe the dependency.

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your maven setup?  But you can download the Guava jar from the github site.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I download `memory-measurer` jar from github. I didn't know I can get `memory-measurer` from maven.

Comment: What is the complexity of the operation measure?

Comment: @rodi Linear in the result, but with a pretty high constant factor due to reflection.

Comment: O(N bytes * reflection constant) you mean?

Comment: @rodi Yes, that's what I had in mind.

Comment: I mean, it's also O(# objects in the object graph), which is somewhat tighter I suppose?  For e.g. an int array it'll be O(1).

Comment: I went with JAMM per the answer below, you can get it from Ivy/SBT and it does not require Guava (which I often avoid from scala). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Wonder if I should use this version instead https://github.com/msteindorfer/memory-measurer as DimitrisAndreou's version is not maintained any more?

Comment: is this available in maven central? I can't seem to get the library from maven. is there any private distribution for this package?

Comment: memory-measurer jar not working. I passed jar like this: -javaagent:D:\company\javaagents\object-explorer.jar

Comment: Error message says Instrumentation is not setup properly. You have to pass -javaagent:path/to/object-explorer.jar to the java interpreter

Answer (score 19):

The `java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation` class provides a nice way to get the size of a Java Object, but it requires you to define a `premain` and run your program with a java agent. This is very boring when you do not need any agent and then you have to provide a dummy Jar agent to your application.

So I got an alternative solution using the `Unsafe` class from the `sun.misc`. So, considering the objects heap alignment according to the processor architecture and calculating the maximum field offset, you can measure the size of a Java Object. In the example below I use an auxiliary class `UtilUnsafe` to get a reference to the `sun.misc.Unsafe` object.

```
private static final int NR_BITS = Integer.valueOf(System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model"));
private static final int BYTE = 8;
private static final int WORD = NR_BITS/BYTE;
private static final int MIN_SIZE = 16; 

public static int sizeOf(Class src){
    //
    // Get the instance fields of src class
    // 
    List<Field> instanceFields = new LinkedList<Field>();
    do{
        if(src == Object.class) return MIN_SIZE;
        for (Field f : src.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if((f.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == 0){
                instanceFields.add(f);
            }
        }
        src = src.getSuperclass();
    }while(instanceFields.isEmpty());
    //
    // Get the field with the maximum offset
    //  
    long maxOffset = 0;
    for (Field f : instanceFields) {
        long offset = UtilUnsafe.UNSAFE.objectFieldOffset(f);
        if(offset > maxOffset) maxOffset = offset; 
    }
    return  (((int)maxOffset/WORD) + 1)*WORD; 
}
class UtilUnsafe {
    public static final sun.misc.Unsafe UNSAFE;

    static {
        Object theUnsafe = null;
        Exception exception = null;
        try {
            Class<?> uc = Class.forName("sun.misc.Unsafe");
            Field f = uc.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            theUnsafe = f.get(uc);
        } catch (Exception e) { exception = e; }
        UNSAFE = (sun.misc.Unsafe) theUnsafe;
        if (UNSAFE == null) throw new Error("Could not obtain access to sun.misc.Unsafe", exception);
    }
    private UtilUnsafe() { }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about this: ((int)maxOffset/WORD) + 1)*WORD, but I think it does work as I'm pretty sure 64 bit variables are never crosssing an 8 byte boundary in a 64-bit VM. Good code otherwise, although you could of course get rid of the whole map making effort. I made my own version which also handles object arrays here: http://tinybrain.de/1011517 (would still need to add primitive arrays).