# NPE when calling getObjectSize()

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

In reference to  : [Calculate size of Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java)

I tried to run this program and get the size of the object created

```
  //main 
 while(true){
        Integer x=new Integer(50);
        System.out.println("HashCode of this object="+x.hashCode()+" 
                  ,  with Size of "+ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(x));
        i++;
}

 The output -- NullPointerException is thrown when getObjectSize() is invoked.

   new Integer() -->
```

should have created a new wrapper object. Instead it creates NPE. Why ?

java version "1.6.0_65"
Apple OSX - 10.9.1 
--Ignore Syntax errors

Comment: That `ObjectSizeFetcher` requires that it be run as an agent. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/package-summary.html for details.

Comment: Did you follow all the steps in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/52682/1343161)?

Comment: @SamYonnou - missed the basic of setup :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the static field `ObjectSizeFetcher.instrumentation` was `null` when you called `ObjectSizeFetcher.getObjectSize(x)`.

You should call method `ObjectSizeFetcher.premain(String args, Instrumentation inst)` before, with a non-null `inst` argument.