# Getting length of a number's bits

Tags: java, bit

```
  int g = 269;//1_0000_1101
    System.out.println( length(Integer.toBinaryString(g)));
```

This will print 18(why?), but I want it to print 9. How can I do that?

Comment: Where is your `length()` method? Using `Integer.toBinaryString(g).length()` will print `9`.

Comment: import static oracle.jrockit.jfr.events.Bits.length; Wrong import, I guess. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see what that method does? Why are you using that, if you want length of the string?

Comment: Used netbeans autoimport and it somehow imported it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(g).length());`

Would print out the length of the returned `String` from `toBinaryString`. You are measuring the length of the statement otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Integer object for your whole number, the getObjectSize(Object o) method in the  Instrumentation library is your guy:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/Instrumentation.html

There are a few threads on this.

- [Calculate size of Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java)
- [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)
- http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077496/testing-debugging/java-tip-130--do-you-know-your-data-size-.html

Cheers!