# What would be the size of the class object?

Tags: java

What would be the size of the class object?

```
public class Example {

    int x = 10;
    String name = "Anuj Kumar";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("hello java");
    }

}
```

Your help would be highly appreciated.

in th given class we have 2 data members so what will be the size of the class object, now when i changed it let say from int to float then what will be the size ?
Thanks...

Comment: Google: "how to check class size java"

Comment: You know that a class file contains byte code (instructions) right?

Comment: What do you mean by "size of the class" anyway? Number of bytes required for each instance?

Comment: And the size would probably vary from compiler to compiler / java version to version

Comment: @anuj can you more specific on your question?

Comment: Which size are you looking for: the size of the .class file, the amount of memory the class definition occupies, the amount of memory an instance occupies, the number of bytes it requires to serialize (by a specific mechanism)...?

Comment: 11 lines? What exactly do you want to know, and what do you think you need it for?

Comment: in th given class we have 2 data members so what will be the size of the class object, now when i changed it let say from int to float then what will be the size ?

Comment: @AnujKumar - [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java) might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excellent question ,
I assume when you say size of the class you meant the size of the object of the class 
In a 32 bit os 
Integer object takes 128 bytes 
32 bit class pointer to class type
32 bit flags 
32 bits locks 
32 bits data ie int

String is basically an array of char 
So we have 2 objects 
java.lang.Sting and char[]

So if u look inside the String class we have 
Hash cont offset and value ie pointer to char array

So again 
32 bit class pointer to class type
32 bit flags 
32 bits locks 
32 bits Hash
32 bits count
32 bits offset
32 bit pointer to char array
124 bits

char[] again has size and characters 
So 
32 bit class pointer to class type
32 bit flags 
32 bits locks 
32 bits size
10 bits for actual char in ur case Anuj Kumar
138 bits

Again we have the Example class 
32 bit class pointer to class type
32 bit flags 
32 bits locks 
32 bits for String pointer
32 bits for Integer wrapper 
160 bits

Hence total size should be somewhere around 160+138+124 bits =   422 bits

Please take a look at this talk https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FLcXf9pO27w which wonderfully expains the same

Not sure why people have downvoted the question instead of answering it

Comment: Thanks Ashish for your answer, I really appreciate your analysis.