# Formula to calculate memory needed to serialize file of x megabytes

Tags: json, performance, serialization, jackson

How can I calculate how much heap memory is needed to serialize a json object which is 5 mb of text?

I am using the fasterxml.jackson library in kotlin if that matters

Comment: It's not clear what you ask. Do you mean how much heap memory it will use that code?

Answer (score 0):

This question is to broad and mostly depends from data types you chose for properties in `POJO` classes. For example, consider you have ten `int` properties or ten `BigInteger` properties, you can choose for date `Calendar` type or `long`, and so on. If file size is `5mb`, I assume, it should contain some list of objects inside. In that case, you can create small `JSON` file with, for example, `100` objects and measure size in runtime. You can calculate average size for each type of `POJO` and multiply it by number of items in `JSON` file of given type. And formula could look like below:

[image]

Where:

1. `t` - number of different `POJO` types.
2. a<sub>i</sub> - average size of `i-th` `POJO` object in runtime.
3. n<sub>i</sub> - number of `i-th` `POJO` objects after deserialisation.

See:

1. [Calculate size of Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9368764/calculate-size-of-object-in-java)
2. [How to Get the Size of an Object in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-size-of-object)